# Confused about IEnumerable vs IQueryable difference

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

For example I have a db call

```
IEnumerable<Player> x = _context.Players.Where(x => x.Id > 10).ToList();
```

According to the other questions on stackoverflow: db call returns all players and then .net filters them by condition in `Where` statement.

But, I see in the console that executed query is

```
      SELECT `p`.`Id`, `p`.`CreatedOn`, `p`.`ModifiedOn`, `p`.`Tag`
      FROM `Players` AS `p`
      WHERE `p`.`Id` > 10
```

How is it possible? Mb its because I am using EF Core 6?

Comment: `According to the other questions on stackoverflow` - either those are wrong, or there's a misunderstanding. could you _provide examples_? because as I see it, your code behaves 100% as intended. `_context.Players` is IQueryable, so the `.Where` called on it returns a new IQueryable that contains the filter. the _result_ of that query is then fetched and turned into a List. i't be different if you'd call `.ToList()` (or `.AsEnumerable()`) _before_ your `.Where`-condition.

Comment: See executed query with `_context.Players.AsIEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id > 10).ToList();`

Comment: @Franz, yeah, probably I misunderstood answers from other SOF questions, now everything is clear for me, thanks

Comment: This of course is quite old subject, but you can also take a look at explanations in [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) topic in EF Core docs